# How to Pass a flag value to Custom Action Filter in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, actionfilterattribute

I have Action Method with Custome Action Filter Attribute "FeatureAuthenticationAttribute", I want to pass a flag value to the filter;

If passing flag value is false, it should redirect to FeatureDenied Action Method. For that:

```
[FeatureAuthenticationAttribute(flagvalue)]
public ActionResult Jobs()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult FeatureDenied()
{
    return View();
}
```

For Filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class FeatureAuthenticationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public override void OnAuthorization (AuthorizationContext filterContext,bool flagvalue)
    {
        if (flagvalue== false) // I want to check here
        {
            string redirectURL = @"~/Employer/FeatureDenied";// Redirect to Action Method 

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectURL);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible like above? If so, I am strucking in Filter Attribute that how to implement or to do this. Please help me.

Comment: Where should this flag value come from?

Comment: Flag value come from database, but it is not issue, I want to check is flag is true or false, if it false then it should redirect to FeatureDenied Action method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make routedata like this in Controller :

```
RouteData.Values.Add("flag", true/false);
```

Filter :

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
 public class FeatureAuthenticationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
 {
  public override void OnAuthorization (AuthorizationContext filterContext,bool flagvalue)
   {
        if (filterContext.RouteData.Values["flag"]== false) // I want to check here
        {

            string redirectURL = @"~/Employer/FeatureDenied";// Redirect to Action Method 

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectURL);

        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: just put your flag value coming from database inside routedata as shown in first line of example and then check its value in action filter as shown above.i think it should work for you..@Chandu